# i lost windows 7 effects after accidently modifiying 'compiled resource script '?

Tags: delphi

my forms look dull and windows 95 like in a large project that i have been programming(cant program all over again) i accidently modified 'comiled resource script ' for that project using a text editor,when i reopened my project it asked if i want to recreate some file to which i clicked yes. now my form look dull and windows 95 style, adding xpmanifest component does bring them back to xp theme but what about windows 7,i do not have windows7/vista so i cant test if my forms behave like win7 forms on win7 or not(but probably they'l look and feel like xp) how to make them win 7 style again
   help!
i am using delphi 2010

Comment: Next time, use source control, or at least keep backups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the Project | Options menu, select the Application Section, then make sure there is a check box in Enable runtime themes.

With this enabled your forms should look good in Vista and Windows 7.

This replaces the need for the XpManifest component.

You can further enhance the look by adjusting the property of GlassFrame on each form.

Comment: thanks,will this even work if i have removed 'comiled resource script'? cant find it anywhere in my projects folder.

Comment: When you save your project after adjusting this setting you will get a projectname.res file that will contain the correct information.   You should not remove this.

Answer (score 4):

First check "Project/Options/Application/Enable runtime themes" checkbox; it should be checked to enable Vista/Win7 "look and feel"

---

**Updated**

Open your project in IDE. Click "Project" from the main menu. From the "Project" menu click "Options..." - it is the last item. Now "Project Options" dialog appears. On the left panel click "Application". On the right panel you should see "Enable runtime themes" checkbox. It should be checked to enable theme support.

By deleting *.res file you can loose some project settings, but you can restore these settings from the "Project Options" dialog.

Comment: thanks,will this even work if i have removed 'comiled resource script'? cant find it anywhere in my projects folder(and on my computer)

Comment: @omair iqbal - I assume you mean *.res file - it is autogenerated file that containes some project setting. No problem if you deleted it, IDE will recreate it, but you probably need to restore some project settings from IDE.

Comment: no no i was able to set those settings successfuly. when you said ''you probably need to restore some project settings from IDE'' i thought you were talking about some other settings(settings in addition to what you and rob told me previously )

Answer (score 2):

More important than ALL the advice on how to fix it.   GET A REVISION CONTROL SYSTEM!  And mistakes like this will be easy to fix.  Two popular ones that are easy to use

[git](http://git-scm.com/)

[svn](http://tortoisesvn.net/)  (this is actually a shell extension that includes SVN)

Comment: @ gbrandt: thanks, which revision contol is better svn or git?
just googled what revision control is.....yep new to delphi and programing :)

Comment: personal preference?  Its almost like asking which religion is better.   I use SVN because I've been using it for years.  I hear GIT is very good.   But hunt up revision control on the internet and you'll find lots to read.